# How can I configure ctags to automatically create a hidden .tags file instead of a tags file?

Tags: vim, ctags

When generating a tags file, I would like it to be hidden by default. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do so:

```sh
ctags -t .tags foo.c bar.c
```

The syntax being:

```sh
ctags -t <your tags file> <the files to be tagged>
```